# mysqli_real_escape_string for season select query?

Tags: php, mysqli

at the moment Im using this:

```
$result=mysqli_query($sqlHp,"UPDATE database.account SET coins='500' WHERE id='".$_SESSION["userid"]."'");
```

Now my question, should I change that query to this:

```
$result=mysqli_query($sqlHp,"UPDATE database.account SET coins='500' WHERE id='".mysqli_real_escape_string($sqlHp,$_SESSION["userid"])."'");
```

or is the mysqli_real_escape_string not needed when I use SESSION?

Comment: Use prepared statements *always* and forget about escaping.

Comment: Placeholders aren't "just" about preventing SQL Injection. They also mitigate accidental mistakes - like forgetting to quote, or trying to quote too much. So .. please, use them. It's 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a prepared statement with bound variables, but if you want to use this form:

- I would cast to `int` (and remove the quotes...) if the value is supposed to be an integer;
- You should use `mysqli_real_escape_string` and quote the value if the value is a string, even if it comes from a trusted source like a session as a string could contain a `'` character and that would break your query.